# Cannot drop the table 'tp_ladder', because it does not exist or you do not have permission

Tags: sql, ddl

I have this code above and it shows an error on the `DROP TABLE tp_ladder`. I'm not quite sure how to fix it? And also I have not only one error like this, almost on every drop table row. Any advice?

```
DROP TABLE tp_ladder;

--creating ladder TABLE
CREATE TABLE tp_ladder
(
    ladder_id       INTEGER,
    ladder_type     VARCHAR(50),
    ladder_name     VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    ladder_discount DECIMAL(3,2),
    ladder_price    DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
    ladder_weight   DECIMAL(5,2),
    ladder_height   DECIMAL(5,2),
    ladder_rating   DECIMAL(10,2),
    warehouse_id    INTEGER
);
```

Comment: The message is clear, isn't it? Check if `tp_ladder` exists and if it does, that you have the rights to drop it.

Comment: It is, but what does it mean with if it exists? @stickybit

Comment: Just a beginner on database, no need to be rude :) But thank you!

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude. I just tried to answer your question. Not everybody here is good at English let alone a native speaker -- me, for one. So there might be a language barrier here? Either you don't get me or I don't get you?

Comment: Ok, thank you. If it exists- where it should exist? where I have to create the tp added to exist?

Comment: It's [in the syntax](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/drop-table/): `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tp_ladder;`  ... `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tp_ladder(` Given those two syntax examples will avoid errors if the table is missing (with DROP) or if the table is already present (with CREATE) If you still get errors with the `EXISTS` clauses, then it's very likely permissions.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)